# Tomcat : Context path not being set

Tags: java, url, tomcat, web-applications

I have a web app set up and running on Tomcat 8 with the project WAR file in the webapps folder in the tomcat directory. If i use any of the following links my project works fine

```
http://localhost:8066/myWebApp/home/
http://localhost:8066/myWebApp/booking/
http://localhost:8066/myWebApp/contactUs/
```

i want to set it so the above URL's work but also the following URL's which have `/app` added after the project name

```
http://localhost:8066/myWebApp/app/home/
http://localhost:8066/myWebApp/app/booking/
http://localhost:8066/myWebApp/app/contactUs/
```

i have set the `path` in the `context.xml` file as seen below

```
<Context docBase="myWebApp" path="/app" reloadable="true"> ... <Context>
```

but this does not work. am i doing this wrong or how can i go about doing this?

EDIT :

I can do this in eclipse by going to the server tab, opening the server and looking in the modules tab, so how do i do this on the Tomcat itself

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You maybe use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/):
1. Add dependence
2. Change `web.xml`
3. Set rule in `WEB-INF\urlrewrite.xml`

or [Rewrite](http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/).